# Ajax выполнить функцию по ENTERу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, есть небольшой чат-бот, все работет супер, но сообщение отправляются только при клике по кнопке, а на клавишу ентер реакции  ноль.

Уже два часа пробую всякие варинаты из гугла ничего не помогает (((.

Честно говоря в скриптах, не очень ((( Выручайте пожалуйста, вот код:

```
<div id="controls">
    <input id="textbox" name="sendtext" class="controls-elements" placeholder="Напишите сообщение и нажмите Enter" type="text"></input>
    <button id="send" onclick="buttonOtprav()" class="controls-elements" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

а это скрипт:

```
var username = "";
function send_message(conv,message){
    if (conv.length > 4) {
            conv = conv + "<br>";
    }
    $("#converse").html(conv +"<div class='message-box left-img'><div class='picture'><img src='/my2/a.png' title='user name'></div><div class='mes'><span class = 'current-msg'>" + "<span id='chat-bot'>Бот: </span><p>" + message + "</p></span></div></div>");
    $(".current-msg").hide();
    $(".current-msg").delay(500).fadeIn();
    $(".current-msg").removeClass("current-msg");
    }

function get_username(conv){
    send_message(conv,"Привет, могу ли я чем то помочь?");
}

function ai(conv,message){
    if (username<4) {
        username = message;
        send_message(conv,"Hi, "+ username + ". How are you?");
    }
    else{
        // $("#send").click(function(){
            $.get("getresponse.php", {q:message}, function(data, status){
                // alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                send_message(conv,data);
            });
        // });       
    }
}

$(function(){
    var open = false;
    var conv = $("#converse").html();
    get_username(conv);
    $("#send").click(function(){
        var usermsg = $("#textbox").val();
        conv = $("#converse").html();
        console.log(conv.length);
        if (usermsg != "") {
            $("#textbox").val("");
            if (conv.length > 4) {
                conv = conv + "<br>";
            }
            $("#converse").html(conv + "<div class='message-box right-img'><div class='picture'><img src='/my2/user.png' title='user name'></div><div class='mes'><span><span id='chat-user'>Пользователь: </span><p>" + usermsg + "</p></span></div></div>");
            $("#converse").scrollTop($("#converse").prop("scrollHeight"));
            conv = $("#converse").html();
            ai(conv,usermsg);
        }
    });
    $("#chat-button").click(function(){
        $("#chat-box").animate({"right":"0px"});    
    });
    $("#cancel").click(function(){
        $("#chat-box").animate({"right":"-300px"});
    });
});
```

Пример можно увидеть здесь http://webcredit.info/
Помогите пожалуйста! Очень нужно исправить!

Comment: пробовал вставлять тели ФОРМ и добавлять скрытый input submit, но тогда страница перезагружается и весь чат исчезает...

Comment: решил другим способом, импунту добавил свойство onkeypress="usl(event)" и прописал функцию function usl(e) { if(e.keyCode == 13) $("#send").click();

Comment: тогда по какой причине вы не приняли ответ пользователя, который сейчас уже удалился. Он вам давал принципиально идентичный ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в лоб: подпишитесь на событие keypress или keydown у поля ввода и реагируйте на нажатие Enter.

Вариант правильный:

1. Превратите ваш див в нормальную форму:

   ```
   <form name="sendtext" action="#">
       <input name="text" placeholder="Напишите сообщение и нажмите Enter" type="text"></input>
       <button>Отправить</button>
   </form>
   ```
2. Подпишитесь на событие submit:

   ```
   document.forms.sendtext.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var text = this.elements.text.value;
     // тут отправляете данные
   });
   ```
3. Уберите аналогичный обработчик с кнопки - по умолчанию нажатие на кнопку вызывает submit формы - и вас этот вариант устраивает.

Рабочий пример:

```js
document.forms.sendtext.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var text = this.elements.text.value;
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<form name="sendtext" action="#">
<input name="text" placeholder="Напишите сообщение и нажмите Enter" type="text"></input>
<button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: не работало, решил другим способом, импунту добавил свойство onkeypress="usl(event)" и прописал функцию function usl(e) { if(e.keyCode == 13) $("#send").click();

Comment: @arashvg что именно "не работало"? Я проверял свой код, он рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.forms.onkeyup = function(event) { // слушаете событие onkeyup  формы
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { //  коли enter - дёргаете вашу штатную функцию отправки
    buttonOtprav();
  }
};

function buttonOtprav() { 
  console.log('enter is firing');
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="try me with enter" />
  <button id="send" onclick="buttonOtprav()" class="controls-elements" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```